# Building html tags on Javascript in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm creating my html tags on my Javascript because of some logic, but the expected result is not being displayed. I'm trying to get all checked checkboxes and display their names. I can pull the names and the checked checkboxes. But it is no rendering correctly. Here is my code:

```
var amenities = <%= @amenities_json.html_safe %>;
    var appendAmenitiesAndFeatures= "<p class='p-tab-title3'>Amenities</p><table class='table-amenities-and-features'><tbody><tr>";

    for(var i=0; i<amenitiesChecked.length;i++)
    {
        $.each(amenities, function(index, amenity){
            if(amenity.id == amenitiesChecked[i])
            {

                appendAmenitiesAndFeatures += "<td><p class='p-tab-subtitle2><span>&nbsp;</span>" + amenity.name + "</p></td>";
            }
        });
    }
    appendAmenitiesAndFeatures += "</tr></tbody></table>";
    $("#dv-amenities-and-features").html(appendAmenitiesAndFeatures);
```

When I check 3 checkboxes and alert their names, I can see the string of html tags being build properly. I can see 3 sets of tds in my alert. But when the page is being rendered. It only displays one. I really don't know why. I'm appending to a div and build my table using .html. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

hum.... You miss a '

replace your line with this:

```
appendAmenitiesAndFeatures += "<td><p class='p-tab-subtitle2'><span>&nbsp;</span>" + amenity.name + "</p></td>";
```